# Cannot find module 'node:assert' when using nextjs in netlify and mdx-bundler with esbuild

Tags: next.js, netlify, esbuild

Tried adding "assert" import, tried node 16.14.0, no luck. Does anyone know any esbuild loader options or nextjs config to fix this failure?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in my NX workspace(for angular) as well, I could fix it by updating my Nodejs version,
At that time my version was v14 so I update to v18.12.1 and my problem fixed

By the way for updating nodejs you can go to [Nodejs official page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and download the last version and install it.